# QCoreApplication on the heap

Tags: c++, qt

I have the need (for example when building a library) to instantiate QCoreApplication on the heap, and I found the following strange behavior (Qt 5.7):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        m_app = new QCoreApplication(argc, argv);

        //uncomment this line to make it work
        //qDebug() << "test";
    }
    ~Test() { delete m_app; }
private:
    QCoreApplication* m_app;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Test test(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << QCoreApplication::arguments(); //empty list!
}
```

Basically, everything works as expected if "qDebug()" is used just after allocating the object. If not, the list of `arguments()` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be related to [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59047), which was fixed in Qt 5.9 and backported to Qt 5.6.3. The workaround is simply:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        //allocate argc on the heap, too
        m_argc = new int(argc);
        m_app = new QCoreApplication(*m_argc, argv);
    }
    ~Test() {
        delete m_app;
        delete m_argc;
    }
private:
    int* m_argc;
    QCoreApplication* m_app;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Test test(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << QCoreApplication::arguments();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe another way to fix this bug is to pass `argc` by reference:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(int& argc, char *argv[]) {
        m_app = new QCoreApplication(argc, argv);

        //uncomment this line to make it work
        //qDebug() << "test";
    }
    ~Test() { delete m_app; }
private:
    QCoreApplication* m_app;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Test test(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << QCoreApplication::arguments(); //empty list!
}
```

In addition, you don't need to create `QCoreApplication` on the heap, having it as an automatic member of `Test` is fine, i.e. `QCoreApplication m_app`.

Comment: I agree, that should work too, although I haven't tested it. And true, for this example there is no need to allocate `QCoreApplication` on the heap... but then I would not need the `Test` class either. In the real code, instances of `Test` and `QCoreApplication` do not have the same lifetime. The bug however, does not show up if `QCoreApplication` is allocated on the stack.